# Connecting to a remote apache server

Tags: mysql, apache, authentication, server

I need to connect to the server "http://ec2-52-57-235-167.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/" . I have the server's username and password access. I tried accessing from Filezilla but it says the "Invalid protocols specified."

What is the recommended way to access this server remotely from the internet so that I can access its files and edit its contents.

The server is hosted online now I want to access it from my local machine.

P.S. I also tried to find out the I.P address of this url but can't seem to figure out by the command "Tracert" in the command line.

Thanks.

Comment: it seems that this server is hosted on AWS. Do you have access to AWS console? Whoever the owner is, he/she needs to open the ssh port

Comment: I am not the owner of this host. However, isn't it possible to access from some other protocol? I had researched a bit and came to find out that if I knew the IP of this website I could login from the windows machine but I can't seem to find out the IP address as well

Answer (score 0):

Install putty and access the server with SSH connection. Filezilla won't work due to precedence of protocols.